# How to get Lenskit-archetype in Maven extension in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, recommendation-engine

I am trying to create a new project using maven extension in Eclipse . When I try to filter lenskit archetype from the catalogs , it doesn't show up . Something of this type comes up:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can not wait anymore after a whole night,
so I try this(like the pitch below),it's work.
good luck!

Sorry for no pitch, you just need to click "Add Archetype" button and fill
"org.grouplens.lenskit"
"lenskit-archetype-simple-analysis"
"2.0-M2"

then click OK

Answer (score 2):

https://bitbucket.org/grouplens/lenskit/wiki/UsingEclipse

for mercurialeclipse download

http://cdn.bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/downloads/tortoisehg-2.3.0-hg-2.1-x64.msi

and mercurialeclipse from eclipse marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

Have some patience, it's downloading in the background. Perhaps change to the catalog to  "Nexus Indexer" if the download isn't kicking off (it shows no progress though).